# left align a block of equations

Tags: alignment

I am trying to left align a block of equations.

I've already tried this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
<b, \pi_u(x)-x> = 0 \\
<=> \\
<b,\pi_u(x)> - <b,x> = 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

and this

```
\begin{flushleft}
\end{flushleft}
```

and this

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

none of them get me a left align.

[image]

Comment: remember an alignment column has tow parts a left part,  a `&` and a `right part. The lest part is right aligned, and the right part is left aligned. Since you have no `&` on your rows they are all let parts and is this right aligned. Try starting each row with `&`.

Comment: BTW: `<..>` is the wrong syntax here, use `\langle b, c \rangle`

Comment: note that this is using mathjax not tex, so is off topic here, unless you can rephase it to also apply to latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle which stack exchange is for mathjax?

Comment: stackoverflow, mathjax tag.

Comment: @daleif thanks man, you a great guy, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
\begin{align*}
&\langle b, \pi_u(x)-x \rangle = 0 \\
&<=> \\
&\langle b,\pi_u(x) \rangle - \langle b,x \rangle = 0
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: please use tex not mathjax for answers, (`\begin{align*}` inside `$` would generate multiple errors with latex)

Comment: I don't know how to do that. would you please post you answer or edit mine directly?